# Way without nested ifs to make a non-empty list of tuples with a common second element based on custom preference?

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples `(a,b)` with b equal to 1,2, or 3.
I want to make a list of a's where `b == 2`. If that list would be empty, I want to make a list of all a's where `b == 1`. Should that also be empty, then I want to make a list of all a's `b == 3`.

Right now I am using a nested if to accomplish this:

```py
sizeTwo = [tup[0] for tup in tupleList if tup[1] == 2]
if sizeTwo:
        targetList = sizeTwo
else:
        sizeOne = [tup[0] for tup in tupleList if tup[1] == 1]
        if sizeOne:
                targetList = sizeOne
        else:
                sizeThree = [tup[0] for tup in tupleList if tup[1] == 3]
                if sizeThree: 
                        targetList = sizeThree
                else: 
                        print(f"Error: no matching items in tupleList")
```

Is there a "cleaner" way to accomplish this?

Comment: When you want to do a similar thing multiple times, functions and loops are generally your friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just build all three lists at once, then only keep the first non-empty list you find.

```
from collections import defaultdict


groups = defaultdict(list)
for a, b in tupleList:
    groups[b].append(a)

targetList = groups[2] or groups[1] or groups[3]
del groups

if not targetList:
    print("error")
```

This trades some efficiency for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tuplist=[(2,3), (1,2), (5,1), (4,2)]

blist=[2,1,3]

newlist=[]

for b in blist:
   for tup in tuplist:
      if tup[1] == b:
         newlist.append(tup)
   if newlist:
      break

print(newlist)
```

If I understand you correctly, this does what you want.